# TFS migrate single control in multivalue control

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

Migrating data in production from single box combinations to multivalued comboboxes. In the single-value passage to multivalued controls, the first and last characters are cut off. How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm using this kind of MULTIVALUE CONTROLS control (https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multivalue%20control&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: How do you migrate data from a single box to multivalued comboboxes? Do you mean you have the issue when using multivalued comboboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is stored in the format “[value1];[value2]”, and the data is backed by **a field that stores only 255 characters**, you may run into a **character limit** when have long values in the dropdown and/or **select a lot of options**.

> **value**
>
> Optional. Specifies the value to be copied into the field when value
>   is specified for the from attribute. Valid values consist of a string
>   of text that contains between 1 and 255 characters.
>
> The value to copy can be empty.

More details please refer this official documentation from  [Define a default value or copy a value to a field](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/define-default-copy-value-field) .

So the first and last characters are cut off.   If you are also encountering this issue, the only way is  tweaking data in the filed less than 255 character.